# IDA Pro get register values before branch

Tags: ida-plugin

Is IDA (or some external plugin) capable of adding comments describing values contained in registers to every branch instruction ?

e.g.

```
ADD.W           R8, R10, #0x78
MOVS            R5, #0
ADD.W           R1, R10, #0xE8
STR             R1, [SP,#0x1C+var_1C]
loc_xxxxxxxx
MOV             R0, R5
MOV             R1, R8
BL              sub_xxxxxxxx ; r0 = #0, r1 = R10 + #0x78
```

where the comment at BL *sub_xxxxxxxx* would be generated automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The open-source IDA Pro script [**funcap**](https://github.com/deresz/funcap) does 99% of what you want. I'd recommend using it as a foundation and making some minor tweaks to get it to do exactly what you want.

[image: funcap]